# How to apply such like design on Default Dialogs

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to show two Dialogs (default) at the same time, no matter if second one is shown then previous lost its focus but should remain on the Screen. I tried by many ways such as:

```
1) Creating two Alert Dialogs
2) Creating one Alert Dialog and other one Activity as a Dialog
```

but i never achieved my desired task. Image is shown below that just describes how i want to show such Dialogs (default) and layout would be same as to the Default dialog but here i just describe how should the dialogs be laid out.

[image: if image is not displayed then please visit this link]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to show two dialogs at the same time in the same activity.

If you do want something that looks like a second dialog, I suggest you create a layout inside the first dialog that is hidden until you make some selection.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In fact, i don't want to use the custom dialogs, i want such layout on default dialogs therefore i am facing such problem in it.